# Linear decay of support of probability measure.

Tags: probability, analysis

If $\int_{0}^{\infty}|x|dP(x)<\infty$, is it true that $\exists N,c$ s.t. $\forall n\geq N$, 
$$\int_{(cn,\infty)}^{\infty}|x|dP(x)<\frac{1}{n}?$$

No, for example $\int_{(cn,\infty)}^{\infty}|x|dP(x)=\sum_{l\geq n}l\frac{1}{l^{3/2+1}}\geq 1/n$ (multiplied by normalizing constants).

So I am wondering what conditions to impose on P to get linear decay of support.

**Attempt**
 A trivial one is to have P with compact support. For non-compact we can start by looking at delta functions at $\{x_{k}\}$ with $x_{k}\to \infty$. So

$\sum_{l\geq n}x_{l}p_{l}\geq \frac{1}{n}$, can provide a variety of conditions by comparing it with the Riemmann integral. We want $\int_{n}^{\infty} f(y) dy\geq 1/n\Rightarrow F(n)-F(\infty)\geq \frac{1}{n}$.

Even better does $\int_{0}^{\infty}|x|dP(x)<\infty$ give any upper bounds on the decay of the support of P?

Comment: If $X \in L_p$ then $n^p P(|X|>n)$ goes to 0. So I could not follow your question/example.

Comment: I realised. Commented in a haste.